# Radio button won't display in html form

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I am new to html and css. I plan to create a signup form by html and css. However, the radio button is not displayed when I run the html file in browser. I have no idea which part is going wrong. Please help!
Here is my html file,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
</style>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ionic.min.css" />
    <title>Create an Account</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bar bar-header">
        <h1 class="title">Create an Account</h1>
        <a href="login.html" class="button button-clear button-royal">Login</a>
    </div>
    <div class="padding" style="margin-top:75px;">
        <label class="item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Full Name</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="" id="fullname">
        </label>
        <label class="item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Username</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="" id="username">
        </label>
        <label class="item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Email</span>
            <input type="email" placeholder="" id="email">
        </label>
        <label class="item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Password</span>
            <input type="password" placeholder="" id="password">
        </label>
        <label class="item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Contact</span>
            <input type="number" placeholder="" id="contact">
        </label>
        <label class="item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Gender</span>
            <p>
                <input name="gender" type="radio" id="male" value="male" />
                <label for="male">Male</label>
                <input name="gender" type="radio" id="female" value="female" />
                <label for="female">Female</label>
            </p>
        </label>
        <label class="item-input">
            <button class="button button-block button-positive" id="signup">Create an Account</button>
        </label>


    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jq.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/auth.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The css file is ionic.min.css. This is the radio button part in the css file.

```
.item-input input {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 220px;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-flex: 1 220px;
    -ms-flex: 1 220px;
    flex: 1 220px;
    -webkit-appearance: normal;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 24px;
    background-color: transparent
}
.item-radio .item-content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 16px 49px 16px 16px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #fff
}

input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox] {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: normal
}

.item-input input[type=radio],

input[type=radio][disabled],
input[type=radio][readonly],
input[type=checkbox][disabled],
input[type=checkbox][readonly] {
    background-color: transparent
}

.item-radio {
    padding: 0
}

.item-radio:hover {
    cursor: pointer
}

.item-radio .item-content {
    padding-right: 64px
}

.item-radio .radio-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 14px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 24px
}

.item-radio input {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px
}

.item-radio input:checked~.item-content {
    background: #f7f7f7
}

.item-radio input:checked~.radio-icon {
    visibility: visible
}

.platform-android.grade-b .item-radio,
.platform-android.grade-c .item-radio {
    -webkit-animation: androidCheckedbugfix infinite 1s
}
```

Comment: I'm able to get the radio button, which browser you are using?

Comment: google chrome,do you mean you use my code and the radio button is displayed?

Comment: Yea,I used your codes with that iconic css and able to display the radio button.I checked in both firefox and chrome,its working fine.

Comment: Yea, the internet explorer display the button also, just chrome wont work. Do you have any idea about this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you write a class for that radio and style it.Check whether its working else check in the developer tool whether the radio button is there or not.

Comment: I have checked the developer tool, the radio button is over there just it is transparent. Do you have any tutorial to style the radio button? I am not very sure about this.

Comment: I have followed this tutorial https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953 and added the css code for the radio button inside the style tag but wont work

Comment: "I have checked the developer tool, the radio button is over there just it is transparent."--> try to remove that transparent property in the devleoper tool by giving display:block;

Comment: How to check which css giving display block in developer tool?

Comment: ok,I found the solution,remove this webkit-appearance: none; in the css file, thanks for help

Comment: Cool,But that webkit-appearance: none; is given only for the input[type=number] right?

Comment: I mean the webkit-appearance: none inside the css file,no the html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the -webkit-appearance: none; in css file to -webkit-appearance: normal; for item-input input.

Answer (score 2):

Try To Put CSS Inline inside style tag if radio button is visible than might be loading css file problem in your case

Comment: The other style and font is working ,just the radio button wont display